# restrict search to specific city - ArcGIS JS API 3.31

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geocoding, widget, search

I'd like to use the Search widget to search for addresses and intersections in a custom web app (JS v3.31).  Is there any way to restrict this search to a particular city?

I see how to restrict it to a specified extent, but this is not good enough for us; our basemaps are made only for the city borders, and any extent will include some areas outside of our map.
(This question also post on Geonet , with no responses)

Answer (score 1):

I do not see that as one of the options for the Search widget. If it truly is not an option in the OOTB widget, you can always write your own widget - use an HTML text box, maybe an autocomplete library like [jQuery UI Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), and wire it up to use the [Locator task](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/locator-amd.html#suggestlocations), and after you get the results do your additional geometry filter using the [Geometry Engine](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/esri.geometry.geometryengine-amd.html#contains).

Comment: thanks - i was able to use the geocoder REST API and append the city to the singleLine parameter, seems to work...I haven't yet figured out how to populate a dropdown with the suggestions, but Ill look at using JQuery as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the source(s) for the Search widget, you can specify a "suffix" (and "prefix") that will add a certain string. This should work ok as long as your users only type in the address and doesn't add city/zip etc.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/search-amd.html#sources